# Using Knockout click binding handler and javascript bind (ECMAScript 5)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, binding

I have problems understanding why the following code does not work in Knockout.

### Example

In javascript, myFunction **.bind(**...**)** should return a function containing a call to the FUNCTION1 with the supplied parameters. Am I right?

Theoretically, the following code should work, the passed parameter 'hey' should be received by the this.path.to.method function.

However, it does not, I am getting something like the ViewModel instance instead, followed by the event object.

### Why?

I am wondering what it exactly does, to understand if I can use .bind or will I always be forced to wrap it inside a function(){ /* any call here ... */ } within the knockout binding 'click'.

JSFiddle link: **http://jsfiddle.net/darknessm0404/X2yd7/**

```
<a data-bind="click: path.to.method.bind('hey', $data)">
    Why p1 and p2 do not receive the good parameters with arguments like ['hey', $data] when click happens?
</a>

function VM(){
    // In my model, I am namespacing things this way:
    this.path = {
        to: {
            method: function(p1, p2) {
                console.log(((p1 === 'hey')?'First parameter is as expected':'First parameter is NOT as expected'));
                debugger;
            }
        }
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

JSFiddle link: **http://jsfiddle.net/darknessm0404/X2yd7/**

### Yes it works...

...with **data-bind="click: function(){ path.to.method('hey', $data); }"**

However, it's less readable than the other one.

What do I not understand with the **.bind** call?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
<a data-bind="click: path.to.method.bind($data, 'hey')">
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/X2yd7/2/)

See [knockout doc's example](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html#note-2-accessing-the-event-object-or-passing-more-parameters).

Actually, the first parameter to `bind` will be passed as the `this` value in your function. 
So **the first param in your function is the second param in `bind`**.

Check [js doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> Syntax
>
> fun.bind(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
>
> Parameters
>
> thisArg The value to be passed as the this parameter to the
>   target function when the bound function is called. The value is
>   ignored if the bound function is constructed using the new operator.

Comment: Yeah it's the thisArg, I was searching for the spec when you posted this ^^ I forgot it was working as .call and .apply!

Comment: @MykaEyl That's actually the point of this method. Thanks for making me 4k+ :)

Comment: Well in my case I didn't "need" to rewrite "this" as I am not using it. I was using it only to call a method (which was not using the this keyword) so I messed up my mind ^^ Congrats for your 4k ;)